# Issues in the Rust reference book

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#capture-modes

```
struct SetVec {
    set: HashSet<u32>,
    vec: Vec<u32>
}

impl SetVec {
    fn populate(&mut self) {
        let vec = &mut self.vec;
        self.set.iter().for_each(|&n| {
            vec.push(n);
        })
    }
}
```

> If, instead, the closure were to use self.vec directly, then it would
> attempt to capture self by mutable reference. But since self.set is
> already borrowed to iterate over, the code would not compile.

The reference book says **the code would not compile.** , but the code can be compiled.
So why？

Comment: Probably because the borrow checker got smarter since that part of the docs was written…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was true in the past, but has changed since and the reference was not updated. Since edition 2021, [closures capture disjoint fields](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html).

See [reference issue #1066](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/1066).